# Should this be flagged or just down voted?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I answered (and edited) this question, but I'm not sure if it really should stand as a question:

[Is there a new Imperial Stockmarket splash screen?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/150376/is-there-a-new-imperial-stockmarket-splash-screen)

Should we allow a "Can you confirm that this is a new feature I'm seeing?" question?

It seems fairly self-evident.  I answered it in a serious way, but I could just as easily have said:  "Yes.  You saw something new, was that not apparent?"

I feel the urge to down vote this question, but I'm wondering if it deserves a deletion flag instead?

To clarify, my question here:  Is there a question here, or is it merely a statement turned query by the addition of a ? and a slight rewording?  i.e. "I saw this." turned into "Did I see this?"

I am not basing my objection on the underlying quality of the question *which is low*, but rather the presence of a question at all!

Comment: It's not off topic, or malicious, or spam, or incoherent, or anything else that warrants closure or deletion. It is however Stupid. Very, very stupid. Downvoting is the proper action to take in response to Stupid.

Comment: To expand on what @LessPop_MoreFizz said, see [this post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one) by LessPop_MoreFizz.

Comment: @Wipqozn Yes, I agree with not closing a question due to its inherent stupidity.  I was more concerned with whether or not there was truly a question in here in the first place.  Slapping a ? onto the end of a statement makes it a question in the technical sense, I wanted to know whether or not it was still on-topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a legit question. Perhaps a terrible one, but an honest question. I don't think it needs to be deleted, though the down vote might be warranted, depending on personal views on when to use that privilege.

Comment: OK.  I can wrap my head around that.